# ZSH alias to grep all aliases stopped working

Tags: zsh

This worked for me for ~8 years:

```bash
$ alias al='alias | grep $1'
```

Example:

```bash
$ al git
clean='git clean -xfde'
echo_git_root='echo "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel || echo .)"'
# etc.
```

I could invoke like `al git` and it'd show all of my git aliases.

Now, however, I get:

```bash
$ al git
grep: git: No such file or directory
```

It appears the alias isn't being replaced:

```bash
$ alias al
al='alias | grep $1'
```

Of course, when I run the naked command (bypassing the alias) it works fine:

```bash
$ alias | grep git
clean='git clean -xfde'
echo_git_root='echo "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel || echo .)"'
# etc.
```

I've tried:

- `al='alias | /usr/bin/grep $1'`
- `al='alias | \grep $1'`
- `al='alias | grep ''$1'''`
- `al='alias | grep \\'$1\\''`

At this point I'm out of ideas!

I recently upgraded from MacOS Monterey to Ventura, and I'm not sure what my prior ZSH version was, but it's now 5.9. I'm not sure that's relevant but it's the only recent change to my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases don't take arguments¹, they're just about replacing text with other text. They are a very poor form of programming construct. They come from csh which didn't have functions.

```
alias al='alias | grep $1'
```

Just says that `al` tokens are to be replaced with `alias | grep $1` wherever that token is found in command position, so:

```
al git
```

gets replaced with:

```
alias | grep $1 git
```

And that is then interpreted as shell code.

If `$1` is empty  or unset, that becomes the same as:

```
alias | grep git
```

But if run after `set foo bar` or `1=foo` or `argv[1]=foo`, that becomes:

```
alias | grep foo git
```

Where `grep` looks for `foo` in the `git` file, ignoring its stdin.

Here, you want either the Bourne-style:

```
al() alias | grep "$@"
```

Or csh-style²:

```
alias al='alias | grep'
```

---

<sup>¹ Well, in `csh` where aliases come from, you can use some hacks involving history expansion to make it look like aliases can take arguments, but those tricks won't fly with Korn-like shells.</sup>

<sup>² well, in `csh`, that would have to be `alias al 'alias | grep'`; for some reason David Korn decided to change the syntax from `alias token replacement` to `alias token=replacement` when copying that feature in the 80s for ksh, shooting himself in the foot as that meant you couldn't alias tokens containing `=` characters.  POSIX specified that interface for `sh` and `zsh` copied it as well, but in `zsh`, you can also do `aliases['=']=uname` there to work around the limitation (if you ever wanted `'='` to be replaced with `uname`).</sup>

Comment: "Aliases don't take arguments"... I should've known that! I know it's a very primitive tool, and yet I missed the forest for the trees. Thank you for such an excellent answer.